# ASP.NET - Razor. Rewrite URL on the fly

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, razor

Is it possible to rewrite URL on the fly, only when a part of the server code has already been processed for the "raw" URL and it becomes clear the parameters must not be revealed to the user? Like, I want to proccess all the GET parameters in my page code on the server and create a tracking record in the database, then serve the user the page but change URL to parameterless in the browser.

I guess all the web.config referred module techniques won't work as they offer URL rewriting *before* request is passed to the page code on the server. But it comes in my case that I receive an ugly URL from google adwords clicks and I do like it tracked 'as is' in my database, and I do certainly not like it show to user in her brower's bar.

At the same time I would like to keep URL unchanged without applying the URL rewrite most of the time unless some particular parameter shows up in it (like ref=adwords) so that any paramter written by hand or posted back would be displayed in the address bar.

Is it possible to do so by any means?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing an `ActionFilter` that would (if your controller or method is decorated with it) intersect your initial request, do all the necessary processiong and then redirect back to the requested page only indicating, that processing has been done?

This would be my first thought.